# Can't generate Input Mappings for a SQL query in Data Service

Tags: mysql, input, mapping, generate

I can't generate input mappings for a SQL query in a data service.
[Input Mapping setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnZ08.png)

When I make the call I got this error:

> [2024-01-02 11:24:11,955] ERROR {DBInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Error in in-only message receiver DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
> DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
> Nested Exception:-
> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':FirstName,:LastName,:Email,:Salary)' at line 1
> DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
> Source Data Service:-
> Name: RDBMSDataService
> Location: C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps-1234\1704191032756TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\RDBMSDataService_1.0.0\RDBMSDataService-1.0.0.dbs
> Description: maria db data service example
> Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
> Current Request Name: _post_employees
> Current Params: {Salary=10000, Email=Will101@gmail.com, FirstName=Marchino, LastName=Smith}
> Nested Exception:-
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':FirstName,:LastName,:Email,:Salary)' at line 1
>
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:117)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:66)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:368)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:40)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:52)
> at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:379)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:438)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:186)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I tried to add the ' and " to the dynamic fields making the query, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `employees`(`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Salary`) 
VALUES (':FirstName', ':LastName', ':Email', ':Salary')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `employees`(`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Salary`) 
VALUES (":FirstName", ":LastName", ":Email", ":Salary")
```

Also tried to create the mapping manually using the "Add new" blue button without success.